# Using Jumps directly in RET register

Tags: assembly, buffer, stack-overflow, shellcode

I am working on a buffer overflow problem in which an input string must overwrite RET (obviously) with the address of my shellcode that is also in my input string.

I have researched and found it is not easy to determine the memory address of a buffer like that at run time.

I also learned about relative jumps.  Is it possible to overwrite RET with a relative jump to an earlier part of the stack (and my string) where the shellcode begins?  I don't know if that would work or not.

Basically it would look something like this:
./program 90909090909090/bin/sh/00RELATIVE_JUMP_HERE

obviously all of it would be in machine code, this is just to give the idea of what I am trying to accomplish.

Thanks

Comment: A code sample with a more detailed description of what you're attempting would help.

Comment: A common technique in Win32 (where binaries are already compiled and don't change) is to make the return address point to a 'JMP ESP' instruction, which jumps to the shellcode.

Comment: There isn't much code to show.  All ./program does is create a buffer of 33 bytes, and then reads ARG[1] in to that.  That's it...

Answer (score 1):

What you overwrite in a stack overflow is not a RET instruction, it is a return address. So you don't overwrite machine code, but a pointer to machine code. There are indeed techniques to keep jumping to interesting pieces of code, google for ret-into-libc and return-oriented programming.

On a similar note, a famous technique is the "trampoline" technique, where you make your return address point to a 'JMP ESP' instruction that jumps back into your overflowed buffer.